# Javascript replace content in <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML code, and there are some `<li>` tags in it. I plan to use `Speed 1`, `Speed 2`, `Speed 3`, etc. to replace `Content`. How can I do it on Javascript ?

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Content <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:xxxx">Speed 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Speed 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Speed 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Speed 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Speed 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Could someone give me advice?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$('li a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('button').text($(this).text());    
});
```

<kbd><kbd><kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4WNGU/)</kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: "I heard you like <kbd>`s [...]"

Answer (score 2):

I had misunderstood the problem and have changed the solution to fix it:

```
$(".dropdown-menu > li > a").click( function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().parent().prev().text($(this).text());
})
```

You could use one of the button classes or even the button html tag to address the change but by using relative paths you will adress the right element without risking to change other buttons on your page.

### [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QfD5p/)

Answer (score 0):

answer for you question ...........:

http://jsfiddle.net/MFmwy/

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Content <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href=# onclick=javascript:xxxx>Speed 1</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Speed 2</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Speed 3</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Speed 4</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Speed 5</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is still a problem. The `<a href=#>` does not work. Could you give me some advice to display `Speed X` and `<a href=#>` is effective ??

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is still a problem. The `<a href=#>` does not work. Could you give me some advice to display `Speed X` and `<a href=#>` is effective ??

Comment: I am not clear with your question .. you want href=speed x if value =speed x right?

Comment: Hm... `<a href=#>` is an url which I should link to. And replace content according to `<li a>` is another thing.

Comment: This is another way to realize it. But there is still a problem. Could you help me ??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699661/javascript-submit-a-form-according-to-select-option

Comment: Yes, maybe you can help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699661/javascript-submit-a-form-according-to-select-option. Thank you !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is still a problem. That is the string `Content` is display again when I refresh this `html` file. Do you have some ways to replace `Content` forever ????

Comment: so what do u want in place of content when u reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Content <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href=# onclick=javascript:xxxx>Speed 1</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>Speed 2</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>Speed 3</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>Speed 4</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>Speed 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('li a').click(function(){
  $('button').text($(this).text());

});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3eba/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to watch that you **don't** replace the `<span class="caret"></span>`, so you'll need to modify the HTML slightly to add an extra `span` for the content:

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span>Content</span><span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Speed 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Speed 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Speed 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Speed 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Speed 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('li a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('button span:first').text($(this).text());
});
```

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbnmf/2/)**

**EDIT: Another Alternative**

Based on a comment you made in another answer about loading the content on page refresh, you can take advantage of the 'hash' part of the page address. Therefore

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span>Content</span><span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#speed1">Speed 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#speed2">Speed 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#speed3">Speed 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#speed4">Speed 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#speed5">Speed 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', onChangeSelectedSpeed);

function onChangeSelectedSpeed() {
    $("li a[href="+window.location.hash+"]").each(function(){
        $('button span:first').text($(this).text());
    });
}

//Trigger hashchange on page load (on DOM ready)
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

And here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbnmf/3/)** showing it work (although the page refresh won't be demonstrable there).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is still a problem. The `<a href=#>` does not work. Could you give me some advice to display `Speed X` **and** `<a href=#>` is effective ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I've corrected the copy-paste error in the sample code if that's what you meant.