# Javascript submit a form according to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I plan to submit a form according to the `option`. But there is a javascript problem. I want to submit the form but I don't know the following code how to program. And the submit url is `/dashboard/speed?speed=xxx` Could someone help me ? Thanks a lot !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name=population_speed] option").click(function(){
       var rate = $(this).attr('value');
       var url = "/dashboard/speed?speed=" + rate + "&id=123456";
    $("#speed_form").attr("action", url);
    /*
      What should I do next ??
    */
});
</script>

<div class="btn-group">
<form id="speed_form" class="form-inline pull-right">
<select name="population_speed">
  <option value="1">1 Rate</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: use window.location = url;

Comment: try another way document.getElementById('formId').submit();

Comment: I think it would help you : $("#speed_form").attr("action", url).submit();

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form with:

```
  $("#speed_form").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to submit the form, which you can do immediately after setting the `action` property (`.attr()` *probably* works too, but it's actually the property you should be setting):

```
$("#speed_form").prop("action", url).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit form with `$("#speed_form").submit();` like;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name=population_speed] option").click(function(){
       var rate = $(this).attr('value');
       var url = "/dashboard/speed?speed=" + rate + "&id=123456";
    $("#speed_form").attr("action", url);
    $("#speed_form").submit();

});
</script>

<div class="btn-group">
<form id="speed_form" class="form-inline pull-right">
<select name="population_speed">
  <option value="1">1 Rate</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

You can see working demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/4YmyL/**

Answer (score 0):

it would also help you in single line :

replace

```
$("#speed_form").attr("action", url);
```

to

```
$("#speed_form").attr("action", url).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to mimic the submit button with a select, there's no need to mimic all the native form functionality. So here's my approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name=speed]").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()!=""){
            $("#speed_form").submit();
        }
    });
</script>
<div class="btn-group">
<form id="speed_form" class="form-inline pull-right" action="/dashboard/speed" method="get">
<select name="speed">
  <option value="">Select your speed</option>
  <option value="1">1 Rate</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123456" />
</form>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hCUG/)